# Compare dates from a log file with system date. bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have an issue where I need to compare the date in a log file with the system date. I am trying to create a script that will send an email when the server restarts. However the issue is that when the Server restarts its creates a new log, the script I have for emailing so far is as follows:

LOG1=`grep -B 15 "Server failed so attempting to restart" /home/testing/Server.out`

echo $LOG1 > attachment.txt

grep -B 10 "Server failed so attempting to restart" /home/testing/Server.out &&
    mailx -s "Alert - Server has shutdown and is attempting a restart" email@domain.com < attachment.txt

LOG2=`grep -B 15 "Server failed so attempting to restart" /home/testing/Server.log`

echo $LOG2 > attachment2.txt

grep -B 10 "Server failed so attempting to restart" /home/testing/Server.log &&
        mailx -s "Alert - Server has shutdown and is attempting a restart" email@domain.com < attachment.txt

Now this works and sends the email, however if I sent this on a cron job it will run (and send an email) every single time until the log file is deleted. I need a way to say (only if you found "Server failed so attempting to restart" in the last 15 mins then run the script)

Could anyone advise on a way to do this?
Thanks for your help